Azure App Services & App Service Plan no longer report metrics
Since two days, all my Azure App Services & App Service Plans stopped to report any metrics inside Azure Portal. Around that time, I've removed several old resources inside Azure, including Log Analytics workspaces, yet to my knowledge the base monitoring inside the Azure Portal is independent and should not be affected by that. Especially since these app services were not configured to explicitly use Log Analytics.
As one can see from the attached screenshots, all reporting stopped working around the same time on Nov 13.
How does one restore the normal monitoring capabilities?
Example App Service metrics:

Example App Service Plan metric:

